# PDOException: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in

Tags: php, pdo, sql-update

I want to make a mistake when you update a row in the database. I use PDO for the process. Here is the code below:

```
public static function update($usuario) {

    $query = "UPDATE usuarios SET
                                nombre = :nombre,                                   
                                apellido = :apellido,
                                email = :email,
                                usuario = :usuario,
                                idRol = :idRol
                WHERE id = :id";

    $params = array(
                    ':nombre' => $usuario->nombre,
                    ':apellido' => $usuario->apellido,      
                    ':email' => $usuario->email,
                    ':usuario' => addslashes($usuario->usuario),
                    ':idRol' => $usuario->idRol
    );

    $DBH = getConnection();
    $STH = $DBH->prepare($query);
    $STH->execute($params);

}
```

I'm calling from the next statement

```
$usuario = new usuario();

$usuario->id = $_POST['id'];
$usuario->nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$usuario->apellido = $_POST['apellido'];
$usuario->email = $_POST['email'];
$usuario->usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$usuario->password = $_POST['password'];
$usuario->idRol = $_POST['rolUsuario'];

if($usuario->id > 0){
        UsuarioDao::update($usuario);
}
```

From already thank you for the help.
JP

Comment: You have 6 bind parameters but only set 5 of them in $params.

Comment: It's funny because the question answers itself.